# Android - Class extending RelativeLayout (onResume)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-relativelayout, onresume

I have this class: `public class HeaderView extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener, ProgressBarListener`

In every Activity, this HeaderView is shown as I put it in the XML layout.
Now, the thing is that I want to be able to implement onResume in my HeaderView. When I launch an Activity, onCreate is called and the HeaderView draw the things I need at the top, but if I press back, my Activity will call onResume and my HeaderView is not going to be recreated and the old values will still be there. How can I implement onResume in my HeaderView or something similiar in order to recreate the HeaderView!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant call onResume in the HeaderView class as its is the callback method of the Activity class and the classes extending the Activity class.
So in the onResume of your Activity class, call a method of the HeaderView class something like `refreshView()`, and then your view can be refreshed.
Editted section: 
You can make a `BaseScreen` class extending `Activity` and implement this thing in its `onResume`.
Now extend this class in all your activities instead of the `Activity` class.
This will make to run `refreshView()` every time onResume is called an you no longer need to define it in every activity class of your code.

Comment: I need to do this then in every activity, is there a general way to implement this refreshView() in all the activites without calling refreshView(); in every onResume. Maybe in some XML file!?

Comment: Mate.. this refreshView only works when im creating an activity, not when resuming (on back press). It's  two pictures I want to change! Any idea why? refreshView is a static method.